# How to add to campaign from webform?

Tags: campaign, web2lead

I am trying to create a landing page, that will create a lead in SF, and add that lead to a campaign.

I created the campaign, Set it to Active, and got it's ID.

According to some resources on the web:

http://bracketlabs.com/blog/2011/6/27/diy-campaign-landing-pages-with-salesforce-web-to-lead.html
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqYB

This should be dead simple: Add the data:

```
<input id="Campaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID" type="hidden" value="000000000000000" />
```

With you campaignID and VOILA.

Dang - if it had been that easy I wouldn't post probably.

I use Drupal as our resource management.

The lead is created perfectly, but is NOT been added to the campaign.

Campaign ID is correct.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right campaign Id? If you paste the Id into the address bar does it load the campaign?

Comment: Campaign ID is set correctly after recheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In drupal, when creating the webform, for some reason, the Name and ID of the `Campaign_ID` weren't the same, and it looks that Salesforce does NOT recognize "`campaign_id`" as the name.

The problem is that it seems that this field is **Case Sensitive**. Changing the name and id from: `campaign_id` to --> `Campaign_ID` solved the problem.

Comment: The moral of the story is that salesforce.com is always case sensitive with parameters and values, and most URLs are also expected to be of appropriate casing.